# Parsing XML with embeded atributes in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Im trying to get the value of each or particular line of the XML,but the XML  im trying to parse has a different format that the ones I have seen,the closes I have seen is the xml.etree.ElementTree (https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html),but still cant get there.

For example I would like to get  the value of the Key "Sequence number" of a "Routine Report" as Ident
Any help would be apreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NGKCONFIG Report="ivory_2019-10-08_08h32m26s">
  <NGKNODES Format="1" Version="3">
    <NGKNODE Ident="Default" Key="DocLanguage" Value="en" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="Default" Key="Machine" Value="Pane X234" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="Default" Key="Look" Value="Mirr2012" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="Default" Key="MachineGroup" Value="Mirr1743" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="DailyReport" Key="Owner" Value="Milot" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="RoutineReport" Key="Owner" Value="Milot" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="BackupReport" Key="Owner" Value="Milot" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="RoutineReport" Key="NextReportAt" Value="2020-06-26T00:00:00-04:00" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="BackupReport" Key="NextReportAt" Value="2020-06-26T00:00:00-04:00" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="BackupReport" Key="SequenceNumber" Value="105" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="BackupReport" Key="LastReportAt" Value="2020-06-25T00:00:00-04:00" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="RoutineReport" Key="SequenceNumber" Value="199" />
    <NGKNODE Ident="RoutineReport" Key="LastReportAt" Value="2020-06-25T01:44:46-04:00" />
  </NGKNODES>
</NGKCONFIG>
```

Comment: Can you use `beautifulsoup` module?

Comment: Please edit the code of your attempt with ElementTree into your question and explain what it does, what you want it to do, and if it gives a Python error please edit the full error message into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

import xml.dom.minidom

def main():

```
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("NgkConfig.xml") 
nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("NGKNODE")
for ngknode in nodes:
  if ngknode.getAttribute('Key') == 'NextReportAt':
    if ngknode.getAttribute('Ident') == 'RoutineReport':
      ident = (ngknode.getAttribute('Ident'))  
      value = (ngknode.getAttribute('Value'))
      message= ('Next {} will be {}'.format(ident,value))
      print(message)
```

if **name** == "**main**":
main();